# Cocoa NSTask ouput extraction

Tags: swift, xml, cocoa, plist

I want to run this command  `system_profiler -xml SPUSBDataType` in my **Cocoa** application. After doing it with the help of `NSTask` i get the following output by encoding `fileHandle` output to a `NSString`. But i can't do the extraction of specific key's value. I tried by converting it into xml using `SWXMLHash` and converting to **JSON** using `jsonSerializer`. But it become more complex.

Is there any way to do this?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

 <plist version="1.0">

 <array>

  <dict>

   <key>_SPCommandLineArguments</key>

   <array>

       <string>/usr/sbin/system_profiler</string>

       <string>-nospawn</string>

       <string>-xml</string>

       <string>SPCameraDataType</string>

       <string>-detailLevel</string>

       <string>full</string>

   </array>

   <key>_SPCompletionInterval</key>

   <real>0.13360595703125</real>

   <key>_SPResponseTime</key>

   <real>0.22787702083587646</real>

   <key>_dataType</key>

   <string>SPCameraDataType</string>

   <key>_detailLevel</key>

   <integer>-1</integer>

   <key>_items</key>

   <array>

       <dict>

           <key>_name</key>

           <string>FaceTime HD Camera</string>

           <key>spcamera_model-id</key>

           <string>Apple Camera VendorID_0x106B ProductID_0x1570</string>

           <key>spcamera_unique-id</key>

           <string>CC89657KQR6GDV4AQ</string>

       </dict>

   </array>

  </dict>

 </array>

</plist>
```

Comment: You've gotten some good answers below.  If they aren't enough to get you past this hurdle, then the next step is to extract this part of your code and make a simple example that just does this part (calls NSTask to get the output, converts to property list) and see if you still can't get it to work.  If you can't, then you'll at least have a simpler bit of stand-alone code to share here so that we can help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to parse this output directly using `PropertyListSerialization`
. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistserialization/1409678-propertylist).

I'd recommend maybe taking a look at using IOKit instead. It can be a bit of a daunting API to get a handle on, but it provides a ton of power. I've used it for USB device information and connect/disconnect notifications in the past and it's worked wonderfully. I think you'll find it much more robust than parsing the output of a command line utility.

Comment: I tried to do that. But data i got the error because of invalid data format. The following lines of code are used to get data from filehandle.                `let readHandle : FileHandle = privilegedTask.outputFileHandle()  
        let outputData: Data = readHandle.readDataToEndOfFile()`.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the exact error you encountered? The following works fine for me, which I believe proves this is a valid plist `system_profiler -xml SPUSBDataType | plutil -p -`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below to get the Array with the containing Dictionary.

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "plist")!
let plistData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
if let array = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData, options: [], format: nil) as? [[String:Any]] {

   print(array)
}
```